# Oracle date ranges from unconsecutive dates

Tags: oracle

I have to convert a table into another. I have these rows:

```
quantity   fdate
3          2006.10.11.
6          2006.10.18.
6          2006.10.19.
6          2006.10.23.
4          2006.10.25.
6          2006.10.28.
6          2006.10.30.
```

The problem is that the dates are not consecutive, and the quantity can be repeated lately. The desired output is the following:

```
quantity    begin_date    end_date
3           2006.10.11.   2006.10.11.
6           2006.10.18.   2006.10.23.
4           2006.10.25.   2006.10.25.
6           2006.10.28.   2006.10.30.
```

It seems simply, but group by, min, max, rank can't help me, and I can't find the trick. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps :

```
SQL> 
SQL> WITH table_(quantity  , fdate) AS
  2  (select 3, to_date('2006.10.11.', 'yyyy.mm.dd.') from dual union all
  3   select 6, to_date('2006.10.18.', 'yyyy.mm.dd.') from dual union all
  4   select 6, to_date('2006.10.19.', 'yyyy.mm.dd.') from dual union all
  5   select 6, to_date('2006.10.23.', 'yyyy.mm.dd.') from dual union all
  6   select 4, to_date('2006.10.25.', 'yyyy.mm.dd.') from dual union all
  7   select 6, to_date('2006.10.28.', 'yyyy.mm.dd.') from dual union all
  8   select 6, to_date('2006.10.30.', 'yyyy.mm.dd.') from dual),
  9   -------
 10   -- End of data preparation
 11   -------
 12  table2 AS ( select quantity  ,
 13                      fdate,
 14                      row_number() OVER (ORDER BY fdate) -
 15                      row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY quantity ORDER BY fdate) AS grp
 16                FROM table_)
 17  SELECT quantity, to_char(MIN(fdate), 'yyyy.mm.dd.') START_DT, to_char(MAX(fdate), 'yyyy.mm.dd.') END_DT
 18    FROM table2
 19  GROUP BY quantity, grp
 20  ORDER BY 2
 21  /

  QUANTITY START_DT    END_DT
---------- ----------- -----------
         3 2006.10.11. 2006.10.11.
         6 2006.10.18. 2006.10.23.
         4 2006.10.25. 2006.10.25.
         6 2006.10.28. 2006.10.30.

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, it helps, thank you! :) It seems I almost did it, but I tried with rank() instead of row_number().